# MS-Access Data Type mismatch in Criteria Expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I created a working Union within a query.

```
SELECT tblGlass.Address, tblGlass.Quantity, tblGlass.Width, tblGlass.Height, 
tblGlass.Thickness, tblGlass.Finish
FROM tblGlass
WHERE tblGlass.Ordered=No;


UNION SELECT tblSeansGlass.Address, tblSeansGlass.Quantity, 
tblSeansGlass.Width, tblSeansGlass.Height, tblSeansGlass.Thickness, 
tblSeansGlass.Finish
FROM tblSeansGlass
WHERE tblSeansGlass.Ordered=No;
```

I would now like to add a module to both tables which works out a price:

```
GlassPrice([Width],[Height],[Thickness],[Quantity],[Finish]) AS [Glass Price]
```

So the final code looks like this:

```
SELECT tblGlass.Address, tblGlass.Quantity, tblGlass.Width, tblGlass.Height, 
tblGlass.Thickness, tblGlass.Finish, GlassPrice([Width],[Height],
[Thickness],[Quantity],[Finish]) AS [Glass Price]
FROM tblGlass
WHERE tblGlass.Ordered=No;


UNION SELECT tblSeansGlass.Address, tblSeansGlass.Quantity, 
tblSeansGlass.Width, tblSeansGlass.Height, tblSeansGlass.Thickness, 
tblSeansGlass.Finish, GlassPrice([Width],[Height],[Thickness],[Quantity],
[Finish]) AS [Glass Price]
FROM tblSeansGlass
WHERE tblSeansGlass.Ordered=No;
```

However, I get an error:

> "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: Seems like some column data types don't match.

Comment: Have you tried both parts of the UNION query separately with the new function, do they work?

Comment: Thanks Andre, that suggestion lead me to find the problem. I already checked the first table by removing the union and it worked fine. What I didn't do was checked the second table on it's own. In doing so I found an entry that was half filled in - causing errors. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andre's comment I found the source of the problem to be a half filled entry in tblSeansGlass. Deleting this entry solved the problem. Thanks again Andre!